# Why does my calculator not work?

Tags: javascript, prompt

It doesn't ask for a prompt, can you tell me why it doesn't work? I'm kind of nooby with javascript. That is pretty much all of it.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Justin's Experiment's</h1>



<script>
var ask = prompt("enter first number") 
var ksa = prompt("enter second number")
var rew = prompt("Enter function")
document.write(ask rew ksa)
</script>







</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Because you haven't actually used an addition operator anywhere?

Comment: `document.write(ask rew ksa)` isn't valid syntax.  P.S. When developing JavaScript *always* have the dev tools/console open.

Comment: Check your console, it should have an error in this line: document.write(ask rew ksa).
You are also not using ';'

Comment: @davibq javascript doesn't require semi-colons, that is not an error.

Answer (score 1):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U29DL/)

Here is a way to do it:

HTML:

```
<p id="result"><p>
```

Javascript:

```
var lblResult = document.getElementById('result');

var number1 = prompt("enter first number");
var number2 = prompt("enter second number");
var operator = prompt("Enter function");

var result = calculate(number1, number2, operator);

if (result === null) lblResult.innerText = "Invalid operator";
else lblResult.innerText = number1 + operator + number2 + " = " + result;

function calculate(n1, n2, op) {

    n1 = Number(n1);
    n2 = Number(n2);


    switch (op) {
        case "+":
        return n1 + n2;
        case "-":
        return n1 - n2;
        case "/":
        return n1 / n2;
        case "*":
        return n1 * n2;
        default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Your document.write didn't have any "+" and wasn't calculating the result. To get the result, the function calculate is passed with the 2 numbers and the operator. We cast the 2 number with Number to transform the string in numbers, then the result will either be the result of the equation if the operator is suported, or null if the operator doesn't exist. Then you can easily print the result or a message to the user!

I added `<p>` with id="result" because it's better to print the result inside a tag then using document.write. In javascript, to get the html element, you simply do:

```
var lblResult = document.getElementById('result');
```

Then you can change the text with:

```
lblResult.innerText = "text";
```